# yAxis Tooltip, formatter function, specific value

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to edit the value that appear on the tooltip, but it's not working for a specific data value. It works fine on the default tooltip, but on that specific one does not works.

Is it something wrong? After the 'data' I include that, the valueSuffix works and the yDecimal works. But the formatter does not work :(

My code:

```
yAxis: 1,
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' ',

            formatter:function(){

                if(this.point.y == 0)
                    return 'ON'
                else
                    return 'OFF'

            },

            yDecimals: 0                    
        }
```

It only shows on the screen the default value (0 or 1), does not show my edited one.

thanks :)

Comment: Could you try and reproduce the problem on this - http://jsfiddle.net/XaZJR/

Comment: Strange, on the demo it works http://jsfiddle.net/XaZJR/1/ , dunno what's wrong on mine. Maybe because it has more than one line. Check this screen: http://i41.tinypic.com/303h4s1.jpg , check the "Bomba Degelo" value, it's 0 or 1, it's not showing my edited code :(

Comment: The right link for the screen: http://tinypic.com/r/303h4s1/5

Comment: But in tooltip formatter you also need to add condition which will check if ON / OFf should be placed. http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter